# Did someone succeed in using OpenGL profiler on mountain lion?

Tags: xcode, opengl, profiler, osx-mountain-lion

When running OpenGL profiler on mac os X mountain lion, **the "attach to application" list remains empty**.

Launching an app is possible, but then, trying to open OpenGL driver monitor, i get :
"Unable to launch or attach to application (null)" message.

I'm using :

- xcode 4.5
- openGL profiler from Graphics Tools (downloaded from apple dev site)

I have tested this on 2 different macbook pro.

Edit: The version of Graphics Tools for Xcode i m using doesn't seem to be the last one available. Unfortunately, this is the only one i get on apple dev downloads! [screenshot](http://ourwip.com/images/capture-apple-dev-downloads.jpg)

m i missing something ?

Solved: I was using a wrong (not renewed) apple dev account to access the download page. I had no warning nor error message, just outdated files for download.

I wish Apple added a simple message like : "Warning : you are logged in with an expired account. Please be aware that you are NOT accessing up to date resources".

Thanks everybody for the help. I could have spent a whole week with this stupid mistake.

Ps: I can't answer the question myself because I lack reputation.

Edit: **I managed to get a more recent file but it now appears to me that it's NOT the last one.**

Edit : **I finally got the August version of Graphics tools for Xcode** but i must admit i don't understand the logic behind Apple's dev account management.

File version i get at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/:

- Fresh free dev account --> **March** *Graphics Tools for Xcode*
- ios paid program dev account --> **June** *Graphics Tools for Xcode*
- old dev account (not renewed ios paid program) --> **August**
  *Graphics Tools for Xcode*

Comment: You can have an expired account?  I got the graphics developers tool with a free account anyway.

Comment: By "expired", I mean : "without any paid program ongoing".

Comment: I'm very surprised by Mortennobel's screenshot since i don't have the 13 September release! Mine is "Graphics Tools for Xcode Developer Preview (OSX Mountain Lion) 11 jun 2012. I'll now try with a fresh free account. I'm a bit lost...

Comment: I just created a fresh free account and went to https://developer.apple.com/resources/ (OSX -> Downloads). I get the same list I got in the first place (screenshot link in the question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just installed the newest OpenGL Profiler (Version 4.7 (3)) (Graphics Tools for Xcode - August 2012) on my new MacBook Pro Retina with XCode 4.5 and Mountain Lion and it works seamlessly.

The Graphics Tools can be found at https://developer.apple.com/resources/ (OSX -> Downloads):

[image]

I tried to profile a GLFW using OpenGL 3.2 (Core profile) and Google Chrome running some WebGL stuff. And both cases worked as expected.

Edit: I have now successfully tried running the profiler on another MBP (late 2011) also using Mountain Lion and again with success. I did not follow the guide from Apple to setup the environment as theAmateurProgrammer suggested, but I believe the OpenGL Profiler does that behind the scenes when answering "Enable" to the dialog below (appears when launching the program). One minor thing is that programs to profile must be started after OpenGL Profiler Attaching is enabled.

I was also able to profile Firefox running WebGL, but Safari gave some problems.

[image]

Comment: Comparing my OpenGL Profiler Version with yours, i discovered that i used the 4.6 version. I then went back to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ but i can only find the March 2012 version of the Graphics Tools for Xcode!

Comment: I add a link to a [screenshot](http://ourwip.com/images/capture-apple-dev-downloads.jpg) of the search on apple dev center.Thanks for having taken the time to test the profiler on another MBP.

Comment: Strange, that's not what I see when I do the same search.  You do have a paid Mac developer account, yes?

Comment: I did finally access the right file (with my ios dev account). See the edited question for details.

Comment: I think you should close this question and ask a new one, since your original question has been solved.

Comment: How can i close the question, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGLProfilerUserGuide/GettedStarted/GettingStarted.html) from Apple to setup the environment necessary to use OpenGL Profiler.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I did follow this guide in the first place with no success ; According to Mortennobel's answer, i'm not using the right version of graphic tools... but can't find the right one.